# In Perl, how to split a string in particular three parts?

Tags: regex, perl

If I have

$string= 0000111111110101;

How can I split it into two part as

$s1= 0000; and $s2= 11111111; $s3= 0101;

namely, I want the first 4-bit, the last 4-bit, and the remained middle bits.
What if the three wanted parts' lengths are parameters that indicated by user?

Is there any method in split to do it this way?
If I use regex to get it done, what's it will be like?

Comment: When you say bit, do you mean a single one of those characters? or a literal bit?

Answer (score 4):

```
use feature qw/say/;
my ($s1, $s2, $s3) = unpack "A4A8A4", '0000111111110101';
say for $s1, $s2, $s3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a regular expression or just [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
my $string = '0000111111110101';

# Regular expression method
if ($string =~ /(.{4})(.*)(.{4})/s) {
    print "$1, $2, $3\n";
}

# Substr method
my $pre = substr $string, 0, 4, '';
my $post = substr $string, -4, 4, '';

print "$pre, $string, $post";
```

Outputs:

```
0000, 11111111, 0101
0000, 11111111, 0101
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping and get it from the matched groups using index

```
^([^1]*)(1+)(.*)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/7)

3 Matched Groups:

```
1 Group: 0000
2 Group: 11111111
3 Group: 0101
```

---

Try this one as well

```
^([^1]*)([^0]*)(.*)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/8)

---

Make it more precise

```
^([^1]0*)([^0]1*)(\d+)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/9)